# calculating volume of sphere with integration

Tags: integration

I'm a programmer and I love co-ordinate geometry. Had studied maths in college so been a long time. I recently saw a video on how integration is used to calculate area under the curve.

That made me wonder if I have the equation of a sphere. Can I compute its volume using integration ? This question was bothering me since a while.

If I perform the Integration on the below formula. That I've derived from equation of a sphere. Will I get $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$  ?

$z = \sqrt{a^2 - x^2 - y^2}$

Comment: Hint: $\int x^n dx = \frac{b^{n+1}}{n+1}$. Substituting $n=0.5$ in the expression gives $\frac{b^{3/2}}{3/2} =  \frac{2b^{3/2}}{3} + C$.

Answer (score 1):

You will get $\frac{2}{3}\pi r^3$, because it's only the upper hemisphere.  But this is a pretty hard integral.  If instead you treat the problem as a volume of rotation, it's much easier.

Rotate $y=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ about the $x$-axis.  Each horizontal slice has area $\pi r^2 = \pi (a^2-x^2)$.  Integrate that from $x=-a$ to $x-=a$.  Easy peasy.